# MediaElement IE9 video lingers when switching sources

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement.js and am loading different content into the same player using something like

```
    player.pause()
    player.setSrc(newSource)
    player.load()
    player.play()
```

when a user clicks a button.

In IE9, I am experiencing the old video being shown for a full second or so before the new video starts being played. I understand the video has to load but in other browsers the player shows an interstitial loading overlay until the video is ready to be played.

Additionally I've tried to manually manipulate the overlays but cannot figure out (for the life of me) what event to hook into that truly marks the ability for the player to play the new video (when to lift the overlay).

I have tried hooking into "loadeddata", "canplay" events before calling player.play() and still experience the old video for a second or so.

I also want to avoid solutions that reinitialize the player.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks